# change new image using code behind, c# and bitmapImage could not be found

Tags: c#

there are two sites; user(android) and server(c#)

The program need to receive the images that been clicked by the user. These images(image1) will change to new images(image2) in android same goes to the server.

What I did is:

```
1- split the data
2- check if the images gets a new ID number (new ID number refer to changes been made)
3- change the old image with the new image
```

code :

```
if (berjaya[23].Equals(70)) 
{
    //code where the old image is changed
    pictureBox1.Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\\HospitalIcon\\images\\a3_01.gif"));
}
```

Unfortunately, I actually don't know how to change a new image using code behind. I'm using c#. new `BitmapImage` says could not be found. is there anything that I've left out?

Answer (score 0):

Put:

using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

above the namespace :)